# SecKeyRawSign returning -50 when signing with EC key

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm attempting to write a prototype that generates a set of Ecliptic Curve keys (256 bit), and then signs a message using the private key. I have code that generates and manages the keys which works well, but when I try and call SecKeyRawSign, I'm getting a -50 errSecParam error. The code to generate the keys looks like this:

```
private func generateKeyPair() throws {
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    let acl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(nil, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                              [.touchIDAny, .privateKeyUsage], &error)

    guard error == nil else {
        throw MessageError(message: "Could not create ACL: \(error)")
    }

    // We don't want the public key stored in the ecure enclave, so we create it as
    // non permament and add it manually to the keychain later
    let publicKeyParameters: [CFString: Any] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: false,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: ViewController.KeyTag,
        kSecAttrLabel: ViewController.PublicLabel
    ]

    let privateKeyParameters: [CFString: Any] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: ViewController.KeyTag,
        kSecAttrLabel: ViewController.PrivateLabel,
        kSecAttrAccessControl: acl!
    ]

    var parameters: [CFString: Any] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 256),
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicKeyParameters,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateKeyParameters
    ]

    // On the simulator we can't use the Secure Enclave
    if hasSecureEnclave() {
        parameters[kSecAttrTokenID] = kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave
    }

    var pubKeyRef, privKeyRef: SecKey?
    var result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &pubKeyRef, &privKeyRef)
    guard result == noErr else {
        throw MessageError(message: "Could not create key pair: \(result)")
    }

    parameters = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: ViewController.KeyTag,
        kSecAttrLabel: ViewController.PublicLabel,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        kSecValueRef: pubKeyRef!
    ]

    result = SecItemAdd(parameters as CFDictionary, nil)
    guard result == noErr else {
        throw MessageError(message: "Could not add public key to keychain: \(result)")
    }
}
```

The code to the signing looks like this:

```
private func signWithPrivateKey(_ text: String, _ key: SecKey) throws -> String? {
    var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!

    let _ = digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { digestBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
            CC_SHA256(dataBytes, CC_LONG(data.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }

    var signature = Data(count: SecKeyGetBlockSize(key))
    var signatureLength = signature.count

    let result = signature.withUnsafeMutableBytes { signatureBytes in
        digest.withUnsafeBytes { digestBytes in
            SecKeyRawSign(key,
                          SecPadding.PKCS1SHA256,
                          digestBytes,
                          digest.count,
                          signatureBytes,
                          &signatureLength)
        }
    }

    guard result == noErr else {
        throw MessageError(message: "Could not sign data: \(result)")
    }

    return signature.base64EncodedString()
}
```

Obviously the final guard in the sign function is being tripped, and it's returning errSecParam.

Has anyone successfully done data signing in iOS using EC keys? If so, do you see anything obvious here? Tangentially is there a way to get more information on the error itself.

Edit: To add an important detail, if I do nothing but change this code to generate 2048 bit RSA keys instead, the code works fine. Keys generate and the message is signed. It's only with 256 bit EC keys that it fails. Is there some alternate method for doing ECDSA in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this. The buffer I was creating to hold the signature was too small. I changed it to use SecKeyGetBlockSize() * 4, and then reduce the buffer to signatureLenght after the call. My only question at this point is if there would be a better way figure out the length (other than calling SecKeyRawSign, letting it fail, then adjusting buffer size to the returned size).

The new sign code looks like this:

```
private func signWithPrivateKey(_ text: String, _ key: SecKey) throws -> String? {
    var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!

    let _ = digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { digestBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
            CC_SHA256(dataBytes, CC_LONG(data.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }

    var signature = Data(count: SecKeyGetBlockSize(key) * 4)
    var signatureLength = signature.count

    let result = signature.withUnsafeMutableBytes { signatureBytes in
        digest.withUnsafeBytes { digestBytes in
            SecKeyRawSign(key,
                          SecPadding.PKCS1SHA256,
                          digestBytes,
                          digest.count,
                          signatureBytes,
                          &signatureLength)
        }
    }

    let count = signature.count - signatureLength
    signature.removeLast(count)

    guard result == noErr else {
        throw MessageError(message: "Could not sign data: \(result)")
    }

    return signature.base64EncodedString()
}
```